# Multiple Data sources for C3P0

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am developing a tool that receives different connection parameters to test values in different databases (a plugin for Nagios in jNRPE that keeps an open connection to different databases).
Because the configuration is dynamic (there could be more databases or they can be removed) I cannot have a configuration file.

I want to know if I should have an instance of C3P0 per database or can I use the same instance and just change the URL each time I ask for a connection?

The code is at github:
https://github.com/angoca/db2-jnrpe/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/angoca/db2_jnrpe/database/pools/c3p0/DBCP_c3p0.java

If not, how can I get multiple pool for multiple databases dynamically?

Comment: I am having similar requirement . Can you please help me how I can create multi tenant database connection pool for multiple databases. So basically I want to create connection pool at Instance level(don't want to create connection pool for every database) and according to request i'll ask connection for particular database and access the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a different c3p0 DataSource for each JDBC url. A Connection pool must contain homogeneous Connections: all checked out Connections must be equivalent from a client's perspective. If Connections from multiple databases were included in the same pool, clients would have no way of specifying or knowing which db they were communicating with.

(If you are replicating, say, a read-only DB and you really want Connections from multiple sources to live in a single pool, because they are guaranteed to be equivalent from a client's point of view, you could do that by defining a custom, unpooled DataSource that round-robined or randomly chose a replicant, and then pooling the DataSource via c3p0's DataSources factory.)

It is very easy to dynamically create and configure c3p0 DataSources. See example code [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_combopooleddatasource).

If you capture your dynamic config as a map of c3p0 property names to values, there's also an [alternative, more concise way](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_datasources_factory) to get a DataSource with that configuration.

Comment: I am having similar requirement . Can you please help me how I can create multi tenant database connection pool for multiple databases. So basically I want to create connection pool at Instance level(don't want to create connection pool for every database) and according to request i'll ask connection for particular database and access the database

Comment: @SANDHYASINGH, you can achieve that using org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource in spring. It uses a lookup key to identity the database to connect to. In my application, I create a class that extends the AbstractRoutingDataSource, then store a map (key is the user sessionId, value is db name). WHen user logins, i use userId as key to lookup the final DB to connect to. Hope that helps